# In-App purchase not working after creating new iTunes connect test user

Tags: xcode, macos, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

My problem is testing In-App purchase in my Mac OS X application;  it seems to me that the problem is related to my test account. I could test IAP on my own Mac quite well with a test user account before. But a few weeks ago while I was trying to make a purchase in sandbox a dialog box showed up saying that I should review my account information on App Store, I made a mistake by logging into the real App Store and my test account can't be used for testing now.

Here is the problem: I deleted the old test account and created a new one. Now, when I want to test the IAP the dialog box that asks if I want to purchase a product in sandbox environment and the next one that prompts for user/pass don't show up.

Using NSLog I figured out that when I enter In-App store, products are being loaded and when I click on a product to buy it, app starts buying product with product ID. If I am right, at this stage the prompt should show up saying: do you want to buy product myproduct [sandbox environment]? But this dialog box never shows up! I never experienced the same problem with the old test account.

Any suggessions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved. I can now test IAP using my new test user account AFTER I updated iTunes!